# Flutter type '(dynamic) => Search' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a search function but I am getting the following error: type '(dynamic) => Search' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform', the function in which the error:

```
 static Future<List<Search>> searchProducts(String search) async {
    var url =
        '${Constants.API_URL_DOMAIN}action=search&token=${Constants.USER_TOKEN}&q=$search';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(url);
    return List.from(body['data'].map((e) => Search.fromJson(e)).toList());
  }

  late Future<List<Search>> searchFuture = Func.searchProducts(searchController.text);
  Widget buildSearch() => FutureBuilder<List<Search>>(
      future: searchFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text('test')
            ],
          );
        } else {
          print(snapshot.error);
          print('error');
          return const Text('error');
        }
      }
  );
```

I can't figure out where this error comes from, I have similar functions in other parts of the code and they work fine.
My `Search` class :

```
class Search {
  Search({
    required this.products,
    required this.categories,
  });
  late final Products products;
  late final Categories categories;

  Search.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    products = Products.fromJson(json['products']);
    categories = Categories.fromJson(json['categories']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['products'] = products.toJson();
    _data['categories'] = categories.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Products {
  Products({
    required this.total,
    required this.items,
  });
  late final int total;
  late final List<Items> items;

  Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    total = json['total'];
    items = List.from(json['items']).map((e)=>Items.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['total'] = total;
    _data['items'] = items.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Items {
  Items({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.isFavorite,
    required this.price,
    required this.link,
    this.media,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final String name;
  late final bool isFavorite;
  late final int price;
  late final String link;
  late final List<Media>? media;

  Items.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    isFavorite = json['is_favorite'];
    price = json['price'];
    link = json['link'];
    media = null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['name'] = name;
    _data['is_favorite'] = isFavorite;
    _data['price'] = price;
    _data['link'] = link;
    _data['media'] = media;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Media {
  Media({
    required this.id,
    required this.productId,
    required this.type,
    required this.links,
    this.position,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final int productId;
  late final String type;
  late final Links links;
  late final Null position;
  late final String createdAt;
  late final String updatedAt;

  Media.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    productId = json['product_id'];
    type = json['type'];
    links = Links.fromJson(json['links']);
    position = null;
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['product_id'] = productId;
    _data['type'] = type;
    _data['links'] = links.toJson();
    _data['position'] = position;
    _data['created_at'] = createdAt;
    _data['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Links {
  Links({
    this.s3,
    this.cdn,
    required this.local,
  });
  late final Null s3;
  late final Null cdn;
  late final Local local;

  Links.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    s3 = null;
    cdn = null;
    local = Local.fromJson(json['local']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['s3'] = s3;
    _data['cdn'] = cdn;
    _data['local'] = local.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Local {
  Local({
    required this.full,
    required this.thumbnails,
  });
  late final String full;
  late final Thumbnails thumbnails;

  Local.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    full = json['full'];
    thumbnails = Thumbnails.fromJson(json['thumbnails']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['full'] = full;
    _data['thumbnails'] = thumbnails.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Thumbnails {
  Thumbnails({
  required this.s150,
  required this.s350,
  required this.s750,
});
late final String s150;
late final String s350;
late final String s750;

Thumbnails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
s150 = json['150'];
s350 = json['350'];
s750 = json['750'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
  _data['150'] = 150;
  _data['350'] = 350;
  _data['750'] = 750;
  return _data;
}
}

class Categories {
  Categories({
    required this.total,
    required this.items,
  });
  late final int total;
  late final List<Items> items;

  Categories.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    total = json['total'];
    items = List.from(json['items']).map((e)=>Items.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['total'] = total;
    _data['items'] = items.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing this error ? check in the error log

Comment: this line: `return List.from(body['data'].map((e) => Search.fromJson(e)).toList())`